# Python: download torrent to specific path

Tags: python, torrent

I have a list of magnet links which links to torrents I want to download to a specific path with Python. Does anyone know about a good way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Torrent Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714501/python-torrent-library)

Comment: Can you not just change the current path, os.chdir() ?